# Matlab reshape function

Tags: image, matlab

I need to use Matlab reshape() to achieve the following:

Say I have an image (M lines x N cols x 3). So essentially an M by N image with 3 channels for each pixel as red, green, blue.

I would like to reshape this image to become.

```
3 x total number of pixels
```

where,
column 1 is RGB for image(1,1),
column 2 is RGB for image(2,1),
column 3 is RGB for image(3,1),
.
.
.
         is RGB for image(m,1),
         is RGB for image(1,2) 
and so on ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`reshape`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and then transpose as follows:

```
im_out = reshape(im_in, [], 3).';
```

Note that `reshape` works here (gives the order you want) because it implicitly traverses the 3D-array in [linear-indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) order: row subindex first, then column subindex, then 3rd-dim subindex.

Comment: Isn't it `reshape(im_in,[],3).'` ?

Comment: @knedlsepp Thanks. It's exactly that. I initially understood the question wrong